# Using Custom User Model for authentication in Django

Tags: django

I am using legacy my database in django. The user authentication method used by django needs to be changes in order to user legacy database data.

There are two table in the database 
`tab_users and tab_user_group`

Structure

> tab_user 
>   **`id | username | password | timestamp | user_group_id | status | section_id`**
>
> tab_user_group **`id | user_group_name | can_view | can_edit |can_delete | dashboard_access  | app_access | section_specific`**
>
> `user_group_id` in the `tab_user` is the `id` in the `tab_user_group` which details `user_group` of the user.
>
> *`id` in both tables are primary keys*

Now the custom user authentication needs to be implemented using these field. Login and user creation .

So far I have tried following

```html
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (  AbstractBaseUser , BaseUserManager )
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
 def create_user(self,username,password=None,status=True):
  if not username:
   raise ValueError("Username is required.")
  user_obj=self.model(
   username = username
  )
  user_obj.set_password(password)
  return user_obj 
# Create your models here.
class TabUsers(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=1100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    user_group_id = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.IntegerField()
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD='username'

    def get_user_group_id(self):
     return self.user_group_id

    @property
    def is_status(self):
     return self.status
    
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tab_users'

class TabUsersGroup(models.Model):
    user_group = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    can_add = models.IntegerField()
    can_edit = models.IntegerField()
    can_delete = models.IntegerField()
    can_view = models.IntegerField()
        section_specific = models.IntegerField()
 
  
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tab_users_group'
```

But cant understand how to implement further 
User creation should ask for username ,password usergroup and if section_specific ask for section_id which will be stored in string in the tab_users

`tab_section`

`id | section`

Comment: Also stuck on same situation